# Error while using free command in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to code a function that generates N number of 3x3 matrices(Recursive Doubling algorithm). The following code produces an error.

```
#define N 4

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void CReduce(double*,double*,double*,double*,double*); //Cyclic reducer

int main()
{
    double *a,*b,*c,*d,*x;
    int size = N*sizeof(double);
    int i;

    a = (double*)malloc(size);
    b = (double*)malloc(size);
    c = (double*)malloc(size);
    d = (double*)malloc(size);
    x = (double*)malloc(size);

    //assign vector values-change later
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        b[i] = 2.0;
        a[i] = c[i] = -1.0;
        d[i] = 0.0;
    }
    d[N-1] = 1.0;
    a[0] = 1.0;
    c[N-1] = 1.0;

    CReduce(a,b,c,d,x);

    //for(i=0;i<N;i++) printf("%d %lf\n",i,x[i]);

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
    free(d);
    free(x);

    return 0;
}

void CReduce(double* a,double* b,double* c,double* d,double* x)
{
    double *B,*C;
    int i;

    B = (double*)malloc(N*3*3);
    C = (double*)malloc(N*3*3);

    a[0] = 1.0;
    c[N-1] = 1.0;

    for(i=0;i<N*3*3;i++) B[i]=C[i]=0.0;

    free(B);
    free(C);
}
```

I have not fully finished the code but it already produces the following error when I run the code.

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000023f4100 ***
```

Could anyone guide me on what mistake I am doing? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong.

```
B = malloc(N*3*3);
```

This is right.

```
B = malloc(sizeof(*B)*N*3*3);
```

Note that the `(double *)` is superfluous, it just takes up space on your screen.

**The other answers have good advice,** they've been downvoted but when `N` is small your program has no reason to use `malloc`.  Unless you **know** that `N` is going to get big, then remove `malloc` from your code.  Here, simpler is better.

Comment: +1: also note that casting the result of malloc is more than just superfluous, it can mask potentially useful compiler warnings

Comment: `(double *)` is not superfluous, it makes the code C++ compatible!

Comment: @vsz, code compability between C and C++ is full of pitfalls, this is one. The only thing that is reliably working is interface compability. C++ is a different language, allocation in C++ should be done with `new`.

Comment: Thank you. I got it finally. An amateur-ish mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where the problem is, but do you really have to use dynamic allocation? Your N is a constant, so you can write

```
double a[N];
double b[N];
double c[N];
double d[N];
double x[N];
```

Comment: What happens when N is a much larger value ?

Comment: It's true that you could theoretically use up all your stack space, but since we need 3x3, that's barely as issue here. Anyway, thx for pointing it out, +1...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a suggestion. Take a look at your `CReduce` function -

```
B = (double*)malloc(N*3*3);
C = (double*)malloc(N*3*3);

............

free(B);
free(C);
```

Whenever you see memory allocation and memory release in the same function, you should consider removing dynamic allocation and use simple arrays instead which will do the same job better -

```
double B[N*3*3];
double C[N*3*3];
```

But there is a certain limitation on the array sizes depending on platforms, compilers etc. Some of them reports errors if the array length is quite large in the declaration. So if you require a really large array (like more than 100000 elements) then probably dynamic allocation will be the only way to go.

Comment: This may not be good advice - what if he wants to use large values of N ?

Comment: @PaulR: The example he is using, it's not for large amount of memories, but only for a small amount. However, I will include your concern in the answer.

Comment: @SayemAhmed: Someone already commented on this post giving an objection, the downvoter may simply agree with that sentiment or may in fact be the same person.  Downvotes are NOT public record.